# How to handle a request with one element in a query param array

Tags: typescript, express, routing-controllers

I am using [this](https://github.com/w3tecch/express-typescript-boilerplate) boilerplate for my api.

I have the following route: `GET /questions`

In this route I wan't to dynamically get the relations in the data, for example `GET /questions?relations=user?relations=answer`. This works just fine, but when I wan't only one relation, for example `GET /questions?relations=user` I get the following error:

```
{
    "name": "ParameterParseJsonError",
    "message": "Given parameter relations is invalid. Value (\"user\") cannot be parsed into JSON.",
    "errors": []
}
```

Here is the request:

```js
@Get()
public find(@QueryParam('relations') relations: string[]): Promise<Question[]> {
    return this.questionService.find(relations);
}
```

The problem seems to be, that it recognizes the query param as a string and not a string array and therefore can't cast it into an array. My next idea was to make an union type like the following:

```js
public find(@QueryParam('relations') relations: string[] | string): Promise<Question[]> {
    let _relations: string[] = [];
    if (typeof relations === 'string') {
        _relations.push(relations);
    } else {
        _relations = relations;
    }
    return this.questionService.find(_relations);
}
```

This still doesn't solve my problem. When I make a request with one relation I still get the same error. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the solution and it's quite bohering me that I didn't come to this solution earlier. If you send the request like the following: `GET /question?relations=user`, the value is send with as a string. At the point you send a second value, the query becomes an array. To properly tell that the query is an array, you can do the following: `GET /questions?relations[]=user`. I didn't use this, because I thought `GET /questions?relations=user` was standard.